Does Bayesian ANOVA analyze variance?
Does Bayesian ANOVA involve any analysis of variance?
In classical/frequentist ANOVAs, two different unbiased (assuming the null hypothesis) estimators of the variance are compared. That's where the term 'analysis of variance' comes from. Is anything like that done in Bayesian ANOVA? If not, is Bayesian "ANOVA" a misnomer?
By "Bayesian ANOVA", I have in mind what JASP can do. See for example here, which provides an example of estimating Bayesian ANOVAs in JASP.

What would it mean to do "actual" analysis of variance?

@Dave My sketch of classical/frequentist ANOVA was meant to show that the name is justified in that case. I'm wondering if the name is justified in any way in Bayesian ANOVA or if "ANOVA" in that case just comes from the fact that it tests the same hypotheses that its classical/frequentist counterpart does. I've removed the word "actual".

ANOVA and regression are equivalent in the frequentist sense. Meaning, significant differences between groups is based on explanatory/blocking factors significantly reducing the residual variance. The term ANOVA therefore is kind of a tail-wagging-the-dog appellation. I am not familiar with any Bayesian "ANOVA" that is not basically Bayesian regression. On the other hand, you can analyze the posterior residual variance to make inference about the quality of the fit. My opinion: if you call that an ANOVA, it is up to you.

In Bayesian statistics, essentially all forms of model comparison/testing involve the Bayes factor. So as a practical side note: the Bayesian equivalent to aov() in R is anovaBF() and implements the method described in Rouder et al. (2012).

For this question:

Does Bayesian ANOVA involve any analysis of variance?

It involves the variance of means just as classical ANOVA does. It is not specifically testing variance per se as the name probably suggests. The test actually looks at the sum of square deviations from the means, which is different. As for differences between frequentist and Bayesian ANOVA, in principle they are estimating the same thing, but using different ways to do it. The frequentist ANOVA estimates a fixed constant as the parameters, whereas the Bayesian ANOVA estimates the parameters as random variables with their own distributions.
As an aside, because you mention it in your question, JASP (or its spiritual cousin Jamovi) doesn't estimate what I would call a "full" Bayesian approach. What I mean is that it defines the priors for you when estimating the ANOVA. This sort of defeats the purpose of Bayes in my opinion because the purpose of Bayes is to assign prior beliefs into the model, whereas leaving it to the software means that the prior may create terrible posterior distributions because of a lack of realistic assumptions.

Thanks. When you say, "looks at the sum of squared deviations form the means" are you referring to the ratio of treatment mean square to error mean square, as in classical ANOVA?
